# RewriteRule not working correctly for subfolders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There is a custom CMS and it has `.htaccess`.

CMS has external ERP system that calls php files in subfolder to make manipulations with data. Vendor has made refactoring and remove all php files and redirects all calls to `index.php`

In root has been written rule:

```
RewriteRule ^dbeS/(.*)\.php$ dbeS/index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But it doesn't working now.

`.htaccess` works correctly, because if i'm pasting `Test.` inside `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`, i am receiving 500 error.

For NGINX `rewrite ^/dbeS/(.*)\.php$ /dbeS/index.php?id=$1 last;` - works perfectly for other customer. But this one does't want migrate from apache to nginx

Example: instead of `https://example.com/dbeS/test.php` has to be called `https://example.com/dbeS/index.php?id=test`

Rewrite in `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^templates_c/filecache/.*$ - [R=403,NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^((urllist|sitemap_).*\.(xml|txt)(\.gz)?)$ includes/sitemap.php?datei=$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^export/((sitemap_).*\.(xml|txt)(\.gz)?)$ $1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^asset/(.*)$ includes/libs/minify/?g=$1 [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^static/(.*)$ templates_c/min/$1 [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^dbeS/(.*)\.php$ dbeS/index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ robots.php [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^. index.php [L]
  
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^. favicon-default.ico [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts(code/rules). Could you please do mention addiotnal details like FROM which url TO which url you want to rewrite? That will give us more understanding of issue, thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't `/` be escaped? Isn't it a regex delimiter?

Comment: @Amith, no its not required in htaccess Rules side.

Comment: @Andrii, Ok so you are hitting `https://example.com/dbeS/test.php` in browser? Which you want to keep same in browser and should be served with `https://example.com/dbeS/index.php?id=test` in backend? Please confirm once.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Confirmed

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, attempts; please do try following htaccess Rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^templates_c/filecache/.*$ - [R=403,NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^((urllist|sitemap_).*\.(xml|txt)(\.gz)?)$ includes/sitemap.php?datei=$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^export/((sitemap_).*\.(xml|txt)(\.gz)?)$ $1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^asset/(.*)$ includes/libs/minify/?g=$1 [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^static/(.*)$ templates_c/min/$1 [QSA,L]
  ## Comment following rule as index.php is NOT in dbeS.
  #####RewriteRule ^dbeS/(.*)\.php$ dbeS/index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ robots.php [NC,L]

  ##Newly added rule here for rewrite internal one.
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/dbeS/(test)\.php\s [NC]
  RewriteRule ^  index.php?id=%1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^. index.php [L]
  
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^. favicon-default.ico [L]
</IfModule>
```

---

---

***Generic Rules:*** In case your test.php could be anything in name then try following rules. Make sure either use above OR following rules one at a time.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^templates_c/filecache/.*$ - [R=403,NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^((urllist|sitemap_).*\.(xml|txt)(\.gz)?)$ includes/sitemap.php?datei=$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^export/((sitemap_).*\.(xml|txt)(\.gz)?)$ $1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^asset/(.*)$ includes/libs/minify/?g=$1 [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^static/(.*)$ templates_c/min/$1 [QSA,L]
  ## Comment following rule as index.php is NOT in dbeS.
  ######RewriteRule ^dbeS/(.*)\.php$ dbeS/index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
  RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ robots.php [NC,L]

  ##Newly added rule here for rewrite internal one.
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/dbeS/([^.]*)\.php\s [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ index.php?id=%1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^. index.php [L]
  
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^. favicon-default.ico [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not work too

Comment: @Andrii, could you please do let me know on 2 questions. 1st- Which sample url you are hitting? 2nd- What is the complete path of your htaccess along with your php files path? Kindly do let me know on these, cheers.

Comment: May be there are any problems directly in apache configuration or directory permissions?

Comment: @Andrii, Is your htaccess Rules(without these ones and your tried ones) are working? If yes then we should be Good at that part IMHO.

Comment: directory dbeS in the root of the project as `.htaccess` and dbeS directory doesn't contain any  .htaccess. PHP file can have any name. SEO urls works correctly with rewrite rules

Comment: @Andrii, so how about other php files mentioned in your code? Where are they placed? Inside dbeS OR in root itself?

Comment: They are placed inside root

Comment: @Andrii, oh ok but your URL has dbeS in it correct? like: https://example.com/dbeS/test.php Let me edit Rules now.

Comment: @Andrii, I have edited Rules now, kindly take a look to them and let me know how it goes then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234438/discussion-between-andrii-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: Your fix doesn't work. I think a problem in other place. I have created .htaccess inside dbeS insert word `Test.` to it and have not received 500 error

Comment: @Andrii, I am sorry I didn't get it, you said previous comment htaccess is not inside debS. Now you are saying you have put it inside debS? These rules assume that your hytaccess file is in root not in debS, let me know.

Comment: htacess i have provided is in root.

Comment: @Andrii, ok so when you hit url `https://example.com/dbeS/test.php` what is error you are seeing in it?

Comment: White screen because physically all php files exists on the server and have content `<?php // removed in 5.0.0` but has to be seen number `3`

Comment: @Andrii, I got it what rule is culprit, looks like your one of the old rule, let me edit it in a min now.

Comment: @Andrii, Could you please try my edited rules now and let me know how it goes? Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: dbeS has it own index.php

Comment: @Andrii, ahhhhh, ok. So which request should go to root's index.php AND which one should go to debS/index.php? As per above comments I thoughts debS is empty. What's happening now with new rules?